# Editing a gridview cell using Modal which is shown using rel attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

I open a (css made)modal dialog using the rel="#showEditModal" attribute of a button.

I used it to add values to database then update gridview and got it working at last.

Problem is now i need to edit this values when clicked upon in the gridview.

It is something like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="BtnEditDep" rel="#showEditModal" CssClass="btn showModal" 
runat="server" CausesValidation="false"  Text="Test" OnClientClick="window.scrollTo = 
function(x,y) { return true; };"  />                                    
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This pretty much screws me because i need to send a variable(ID) to that modal

1) If i put it inside the Grid_RowCommand it won't go there until after the modal shows up
tried putting the value inside a viewstate => can't seem to be able to extract the value from the gridview

2) Tried to open the modal dynamically by adding attribute ("rel","#showEditModal") dynamically INSIDE the Grid_RowCommand but apparently I will need to click it again to show the modal (looked into programmatically clicking the button but failed)

3) Also tried it like this(didn't work - couldn't send parameter)

```
OnClientClick="SaveValue('<%= (BtnEditDep.ClientID).Text %>); 
window.scrollTo = function(x,y) { return true; };"
....
function SaveValue(name)
{
    $("hiddenelement").value = "<%= (BtnEditDep.ClientID).Text  %>";
}
```

How can i accomplish this because I am currently stumped.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to pack your function of saving data and refreshing gridview in a service and use ajax to fire it on client side, that's the most nature solution for your problem.